# Artificially made planet

Tags: biology, planets, physics

Could an artificial planet be created considering there is a perfect void, the core is a super-magnet(an artificial planet core made of magnetic metal) that is coated with earth as is our planet and bound with plants and trees(the earth that coats the magnet). The super-magnet given its pulling strength should have a gravity of its own. Vital gases would be artificially injected in the atmosphere. Could such a bio-planet work?

The planet is as big as Jupiter and is close is as close as Jupiter to a sun-like star.

A perfect void is a space that has no breach of gases and is artificially controlled(just like a bubble).

Comment: I have difficulties in understanding what you are asking. Can you try to rephrase it?

Comment: In seriousness: hello @wickerman and welcome to Worldbuilding. Please look at our nifty [help section](http://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) for good information on how to post a question in a manner that will ensure productive answers. As your question stands at the moment, it is very hard for us to figure out what exactly it is that you are asking. What do you mean by "super-magnet"? What do you mean by "coated with earth"? What do you mean by "bound with plant and trees"? Please clarify your question and be more descriptive.

Comment: Air is not magnetic, gravity and magnetism are two separate pulling forces. Gravity is one of those "under discussion" things but as far as anyone can work out is generated by mass. The more mass present in an area, the more gravity.

Comment: Rephrased a bit, tried to explain everything.

Comment: How do you intend to create a planet from a perfect void (i.e., the absence of everything)? Planets aren't coated with earth; rather, they're made of rock in varying amounts of minerals and other compounds.

Comment: A warm welcome from me, too. I still find your question a bit difficult to understand. Maybe you could give some hints about size, mass, a nearby star, and whatnot.

Comment: The planet is artificially created by humans/aliens. Yes they are not coated only by earth, that is my mistake and will be corrected.

Comment: What do you mean exactly by "perfect void"? As in no major bodies around the star? Or not even a star to orbit around?

Comment: @wickerman I am sorry but I have to put a close-vote on your question because it is not at all clear what you are asking. Your question is so short and contains so little information — even after your edits — that we cannot figure out what you mean. See next comment for a very brief answer tho'...

Comment: @wickerman To condense your question a bit and make it answerable, I think what you mean is: "Can an artificially created planet support life"? Answer: yes, it can possibly do that. If that planet was made to be a replica of Earth (along with the rest of the solar system, nota bene), then it can, because Earth can support life. The **origin** of the planet is of no significance; how it came to be there — by natural processes or artificial ones — does not matter at all. As long as the planet is actually there, and the conditions for supporting life are right, then: yes, it can support life.

Comment: @MichaelK that answers my question, yes, so an artificial planet can support itself and life.

Comment: @wickerman Well, no, it cannot support **itself**, not if it is to support anything like life on Earth. Life on Earth is (for the most part) entirely dependant on the **Sun** for energy. If you stick the planet in a void on its own with no star for it, then you are entirely out of luck because the surface of that planet will cool to the point where it is just a few degrees above absolute zero. That cannot support any kind of Earth-like life.

Comment: I edited the question to include a sun some time ago.

Comment: Why are you trying to simulate Earth with a Jupiter-like planet, anyway?

Comment: @Roux just curious, scientific curiosity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably could create this planet, but it would be really bad at simulating Earth.

> The planet is as big as Jupiter <...> bound with plants and trees

You make a planet with radius ten times bigger than Earth radius, and from the same materials as the Earth, so let's say as dense too.
The gravity on its surface is 10 times bigger than on Earth:
[image: some math]

You won't be able to correctly simulate Earth plants at 10 g. 
For example, in [this study](http://pubs.sciepub.com/ajmbr/), arugula shoots were put in 7g for 8 hours per day, the experiment lasted for 4 days. The difference between test and control groups (same sees raised at 1 g) was obvious, for example, average length of test plants was ~7 cm, and  of the control plants - 5 cm.

> Is as close as Jupiter to a sun-like star.

So, the photosynthesis is very unlikely to work as usual. You could try some other energy sources, for example, hydrothermal vents or infrared photosynthesis, but again, those plants would differ from Earth plants.

Answer (score 2):

Do not confuse gravity with magnetism.

Gravity has its effects on all bodies moving in the space-time, while magnetism only on a subset of them. That's why a magnet will pull an iron nail from a table, but will leave a glass of water unperturbed.

Moreover magnetism does not propagate far: as reference, to feel some pulling on a nail from a magnet, you need to place it within few centimeters from it. Ferromagnetic materials can be used to "channel" the magnetic field, but again the magnetic attraction won't operate far from them.

If the block of magnetic material is so big that it can exert a noticeable gravitational attraction on surrounding space dust to make it aggregate in a planet, well, that's to be attributed to gravity, not to magnetism.

Note also that with increasing temperature, like it happens when you move to the core of a planet, permanent magnetism is lost as soon as the temperature exceeds the [Curie temperature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curie_temperature) for that material. You need a different mechanism (dynamo-like) to sustain a magnetic field in this case.

Comment: A magnet can interact with a glass of water if it has enough momentum. :)

Comment: I didn't specify a magnet the size of a hand, but a super magnet, planet core big. And as for the glass of water, look at the moon, a big enough magnet pulls oceans let alone glasses of water.

Comment: Umm the moon isn't a magnet, it pulls water because it has mass, which causes gravity, not magnetism.

Comment: @wickerman the size of a magnet is not important, it if have near it 2T magnet field, then a planet size magnet made of the same material will have 2T magnetic field on its surface. The difference is the magnetic field will fade the same way as gravity, but it will not replace the gravity(which will be a separate/another force from the planet size magnet)

Comment: @JoshKing the moon isn't a magnet, but it behaves like one. English is not my native, and I usually have a difficult time explaining my thoughts.

Comment: @wickerman, you are confusing gravity with magnetism. gravity is always attractive, magnetism can be also repulsive.

Answer (score 0):

It does depend on how big you're talking. Something the size of the moon is far too small to create enough gravity to hold an atmosphere, so no gasses unless there is an outer shell. I would have thought plants would require decent gravity too to hold soil together as it does on earth, though a fine network of roots that do NOT grow might work if the ground was pre-compressed. Any growth would loosen the soil and without gravity it would stay loose.

Typically the cores of planets are magnetic by nature yes but it's not the magnetism that holds everything together, so I would drop the term.

Comment: We are talking Jupiter size planet. Kind of a simulation of earth.

Comment: That's like building the Death Star and calling it a simulation of a tennis ball. Jupiter has ten times the radius of Earth, more mass = more gravity = more atmospheric pressure. Sure with some super engineering you could hollow out parts or layers of the core but it would be easier to build a thousands Earths.

Answer (score 0):

**Don't think so**

Not as in not buildable (it sort of is, it's just stupendously costly in energy and time, we're talking about building a solar system *outside the Universe border*), but for it to hold life in any way similar (or at all) to Earth in a rocky planet the size of Jupiter.

The mass of such a thing would be near or in star mass range. I doubt anything above bacteria can survive that level of gravity. Or if the planet can keep itself rocky and cool.

Comment: Fish would be fine as long as they didn't use gas based swim bladders.  But yes, it would almost certainly end up with a thick atmosphere and strong greenhouse effect. You wouldn't want to go bungee jumping, that's for sure.

Answer (score 0):

Your scenario is filled with contradictions. If your planet is in a perfect void, where do the injected gasses come from? For that matter, how is there a sun-like star in a perfect void with no gasses? Are you "building" the star first?

As mentioned by others, a Jupiter-sized planet is very unlike an Earth planet. Even an Earth-sized planet at the distance of Jupiter would be very un-Earth-like. Jupiter is so massive it actually pulls the Sun off center – they orbit a barycenter so you are really talking about creating two things, and keeping their orbits balanced and perfectly spaced throughout their construction. As each becomes more massive, they need to move further away from each other to maintain balance.

[image: Barycenter]